# Super class link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class hierarchy (simplified) as follows.

```
Activity
SubactivityA < Activity
SubactivityB < Activity
```

where `activity` is an instance of `Activity`, `subactivityA` is instance of `SubactivityA`, and `subactivityB` is instance of `SubactivityB`.

I can use these `link_to` calls:

```
=link_to 'Name', edit_activity_path(activity) 
=link_to 'Name', edit_subactivitya_path(subactivityA) 
=link_to 'Name', edit_subactivityb_path(SubactivityB)
```

When I'm iterating through a list of Activities, this would require me to know the subclass and specify the relevant path. Is there a way to automatically call the correct path, with something like this (which doesn't work) and have it work for all subclasses??

```
=link_to 'Name', edit_activity_path(activity)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveRecord's [becomes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes) to achieve the URLs you want. This is mostly useful in relation to single-table inheritance structures where you want a subclass to appear as the superclass.

Here's an example:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= link_to 'Name', edit_activity_path(activity.becomes(Activity)) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it but it still generates /activities/:id/edit instead of path that's relevant to the subclass.

Comment: Then `edit_activity_path(activity)` should work. Are you using single table inheritance for activities?

Comment: I am using Mongoid which supports ActiveSupport and ActiveModel.